# How do you manage tabindex in a large scale application?

Tags: javascript, html

I was tasked with implementing tabindex across a site with a lot of form elements in the interface. What strategies can be used to manage tabindex in a complex page with ajax updating the majority of ui? Do you just iterate through all the html until the tabindex is organized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, the best way is to call a JS function on `$(document).ready()` or such things. Because  you have enough time to do that and it's not visual.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate more? I think it is a visual issue if a user tabs through your form and there is no logical order to how the cursor moves, especially when you have two-column layouts.

Comment: I mean, if you add them after loading page, It will be done in milliseconds and during this time no one can use his/her tab key.
It's not visual, because if you add them using JS, no one can sense the changes.

Comment: Sure, but lets say I had some psuedocode: $('input').attr("tabindex", ti+1) the results wouldn't be consistent on refresh?

Comment: Try this:

`$('input').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("tabindex", ti++);
});`